# If $N \le M$ , $M$ finitely generated , $N$ is isomorphic to a direct summand of $M$ , then is $N$ a direct summand of $M$

Tags: modules, finitely-generated

Let $N$ be a submodule of a finitely generated module $M$ such that $N \cong P$,  where $M=P \oplus Q $ for some submodule $Q$ of $M$. Is it true that there is a submodule $N'$ of $M$ such that $M =N \oplus N'$ ?

I have a feeling this is not true , but I am not sure. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint:* Consider the special case $R=M={\mathbb Z}$ and $Q=0$.

Comment: What is your $N$ and $P$ ?

Comment: I'm sure you'll be able to find that out yourself - give it a try!

Comment: Do you mean to say something like $\mathbb Z = \mathbb Z \oplus 0$ and $\mathbb Z \cong 2\mathbb Z$ but for any $m \mathbb Z$ , $\mathbb Z  \neq 2 \mathbb Z \oplus m \mathbb Z $ ...

Comment: See, you got it :)